# How to require an alternative js file from a npm package without specifiying full node_modules path

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, webpack

I am using the ES2016 import syntax to load the select2 libray from an npm module (via Webpack):

```
import 'select2';
```

This works fine and loads the following file from the node_modules directory.

*node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.js*

Now within that directory they have a full version of the library which has some extra functionality I need, it is called:

*node_modules/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js*

Is there a way to import this without providing the full relative path to my node_modules folder?

I tried:

```
import 'select2.full'
```

but no luck.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full.js'
```

I think this is the best you are going to get.

Comment: Thanks, that's much better.

Comment: You have a typo in your importing example * import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full.js'

Comment: `import 'select2/dist/js/select2.full';`